# Alternate to sys 2015 vfp command

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro, foxpro

Is there an alternate library available in c# or algorithm that generates unique value in similar way vfp does using the sys 2015 command.

Answer (score 0):

Unique ids can be generated in plenty different ways. `SYS(2015)` is unique only within a given process, and you can get that by putting a global integer counter in a critical section.

If you want something that looks similar to `SYS(2015)` then you could use `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()`, storing the last dispensed value in a global variable protected by a critical section. If the current value is not greater than the last value, increment the last value and return that. In this way the id can run a bit ahead of the current time if there is high contention but real time will catch up in slow periods. As encoding you could use base64, stripping '=' and substituting the characters '/' and '+' in a suitable way.

If you want to create filenames that are *likely* to be unique on a given machine then you can do a lot worse than hashing the concatenation of machine name, process id, thread id and system time (UNC as filetime). You could use the left eight characters of the base64 representation of the hash (after substituting something like '$' and '_' for '/' and '+') to get names that can be used as identifiers, column names and so on. These names are not unique - they just have a relatively low likelihood of collision. By using more characters of the hash in the name you can get the likelihood of collision as low as you want.

Another way is to use above-mentioned concatenation directly, after doing some formatting and substitution to make it compatible with your intended name domain. E.g. convert process id, thread id and UNC filetime of id generation to hex, and insert suitable separators. Then you have ids that are guaranteed to be unique across the network as long as machine names are unique.

If you need short names that are guaranteed to be unique on a given machine or network then you can use a global counter protected by a suitable IPC mechanism. The easiest way of doing that is putting the counter into a table and relying on the database engine (e.g. FoxPro) for the necessary IPC.

Or you could put the counter into an .ini file and use Win32 byte range locking, or mutex files (whoever manages to create the empty exclusive mutex file has the lock on the .ini).

Yet another option is to use a binary file that - by pure coincidence - looks like a valid .DBF file, and to use a locking protocol that - by pure coincidence - is compatible with VFP's locking protocol. That means even C# or Delphi can get integer ids from an id table that VFP manages in its own Foxy way. I'm using such a module in production, combined with a shared memory access method (just a naked InterlockedIncrement() for fetching a new id) that can be used if all consumers are running on the same machine.

The possibilies are virtually endless but a specific recommendation can only be made if specific requirements are known.

Answer (score 0):

One that is even better than sys(2015) is:

```
var uniqueValue = Guid.NewGuid();
```